# Es posible quitar el # de un link target

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

Quiero activar una ventana modal desde el buscador, me funciona con target pero no me guta el # quisiera saber si es posible quitarlo o si hay otro metodo para darle una **"url"** al div, ya sé que el otro metodo son las direcciones de las carpetas pero no quiero y no puedo gastar espacio.

https://www.ejemplo.com/#widget

```
<!-- Link que me interesa -->
```

https://www.ejemplo.com/widget

```css
body{
margin: 0;
}
#target{
height: 100vh;
background-color: #ff0;
display: none;
}
#target:target{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
h2{
margin: 0;
}
a{
width: 50%;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
right: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
color: #000;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 15px;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">
<h2>Ventana modal</h2>
</div>

<a href="#target">Open Modal</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar jQuery con el método .css() para agregarle los estilos que necesites, sólo seleccionamos la etiqueta, llamamos al método preventDefault(); para que no haga el href, ya que te mandará el error por no tener el `#`, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  
  $('#target').css({
  'display': 'flex',
'align-items': 'center',
'justify-content': 'center'
 });

 
})
```

```css
body{
margin: 0;
}
#target{
height: 100vh;
background-color: #ff0;
display: none;
}
/*#target:target{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}*/
h2{
margin: 0;
}
a{
width: 50%;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
right: 0;
left: 0;
margin: auto;
color: #000;
padding: 10px;
font-size: 15px;
background-color: #f1f1f1;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">
<h2>Ventana modal</h2>
</div>

<a href="#target">Open Modal</a>
```

Comment: Gracias, pero y el link? si quiero activar el div desde la url... lo que me interesa cambiar es que el link quede formado sin el # y totalmente funcional.

Comment: Una vez presionado la etiqueta `<a></a>` quieres que la URL se mire sin el #, porque no creo que eso pueda funcionar, ya que estarías enviando a otra página y no sé para qué quieres hacer ese tipo de cosas, sólo por estética? no te compliques la existencia.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es algo que se puede conseguir [manipulando la información de sesión y navegación con JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/Manipulando_el_historial_del_navegador). Internamente no tendrías que cambiar nada en los enlaces  (que seguirían teniendo el `#`), pero vas a ocultarlo en la barra de navegación.

> Nota: Este método podría tener consecuencias negativas si el usuario usa las teclas de historial para recargar la página y moverse hacia adelante o atrás. (En Chrome parece que funciona bien hacia adelante y atrás, a menos que pulses recargar). También podría tener problemas de al hacer *deep linking*.

La idea sería detectar un cambio en el `#` y [reemplazar el estado del historial](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/Manipulando_el_historial_del_navegador#El_m%C3%A9todo_replaceState()) para que se muestre una URL diferente, sin el `#`. Algo como esto:

```
  // cuando cambia el hashtag
  window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {
    // cambia la URL de la barra de dirección con el hashtag
    history.replaceState({}, null, window.location.hash.replace("#", "/"));
  });
```

> Nota: éste es un ejemplo ilustrativo y muy básico del código en JS, en el que se asume que vas a estar siempre en la raíz del sitio. Para que funcione con diferentes niveles, tendrías que añadir algo más de lógica.

Vamos a ver un ejemplo con ese código. Imaginemos que estás en `http://example.com` con el siguiente código HTML:

```
<div id="target1">
  <h2>Ventana modal</h2>
  <a href="#target2">Ir a Sección</a>
</div>
<div id="target2">
  <h2>Sección 1</h2>
</div>

<a href="#target1">Abrir Modal</a>
```

Y sigues los siguientes pasos:

1. Cargas la página y la url en la barra de dirección es `http://example.com/`
2. Pulsas en el enlace "Abrir modal" y se salta al modal. Como ha cambiado el hash a #target1, se ejecuta el código JS (esto ocurre en un instante y el usuario no nota cambio alguno) y la url en la barra de dirección es `http://example.com/target1`
3. Pulsas en el enlace "Ir a sección" y el navegador te lleva a la sección especificada. Como ha cambiado el hash a #target2, se ejecuta el código JS (de nuevo, en un instante) y la url en la barra de dirección es `http://example.com/target2`